# observer pattern implementation in uml

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I want to add a notification service to our subscribers. Subscribers will be able to choose
your favorite sections. When a new article is published in any of them, it will be sent to them
an email with the title of it. We want to provide a solution that avoids docking
between subscribers and articles.
We have an EMailServer mail server. You do not need to know the details of your
configuration, or the sendEMail method. These details are encapsulated in this class, whose
Services are accessed through the Singleton pattern application:

[image]

The pattern of responsibility is clear to me, I will use observer, but I don't know if I have it well implemented.

I had also thought about implementing the controller design pattern but this generates more doubts about how to translate it into the uml, at the moment my implementation of the observer is the following, I do not know if it is correct:

[image]

What I did was, the observer will be the mail server that will notify the subscriber of a new article of his favorite section, while the observable will be related to the specific subject that is the article.

I don't know if it's okay, but that's what comes to mind

Regarding the design pattern, I have more doubts due to the singleton.

Comment: The second image seems to disagree with the problem description. You can't associate any observer with an article which does not exist yet! You're clearly told to observe a section (_Subscribers will be able to choose your **favorite sections**_) and when a new article is added to any of the favourite sections, subscribers should be mailed. Who can decide on emailing? Certainly not the article, becuse it didn't even exist when users subscribed sections. Only the section can know (via its observers) it has been subscribed and send notifications when it's modified (articles added).

Comment: @CiaPan So how would the diagram change? I put the observable instead of in article in section? The rest equal?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Alas I have no tool at hand to create such clear UML diagrams. But IMO the observer should carry the Suscriptor's ID (or, may be, could even be aggregated by it, that is Suscriptor would keep a list of its subscriptions), The Observer would use a section (by attaching and fetching its content). That would be many-to-one. A section would use the observer (by notifying it). The observer would also use the mailing server to send messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the 'mark this as my favourite' action performed by a user (subscriber) should result in creation of an observer object, which remembers the user who created it and gets linked ('attach') to a section observed ('subject').

Then each section should send notifications ('update') to all its observers when a new article is added.
An observer should remember some timestamp or other identifier of its recent update, so it can check in the 'subject' what article(s) was added since its last update. Then it sends an e-mail message via the EmailServer to its subscriber with information about new article(s) (and it updates its internal timestamp/id of the recent update).

Alternatively, the 'update' notification may carry a title or some other ID (URL...?) of the new article.
When notified, each observer sends an e-mail message to the subscriber (whose ID it remembers) about an article (whose ID it received in the 'update' call).

Of course there should also exist an 'unfavourite' function for a user, which finds a corresponding observer object, detaches it from a subject and finally destroys it.

Answer (score 1):

starting with few issue, `Suscriptor` and `InterfaceObservator` naming
then we have Pattern design issue, i think your `subscriber` should implement `Implement Observer`, not be subclassed by Server, then u can use it inside Server as composition but with type `InterfaceObservator`

```
class Suscriptor implements InterfaceObsevator{
//implement here
    }

class Server implements OtherInterface{
//uses Observer
    private InterfaceObsevator suscriptor

 }
```

Comment: Is there a missing 'r' in 'Susc**r**iptor' and in 'Obse**r**vator'...?